# o assync nao funciona no ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou tentando usar o async para poder retornar o valor que o banco vai trazer, mas nao esta dando certo

```
async function emailExi(email){ 
    const teste = await $.ajax({
        url: "../banco/emailexi.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {email: email},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
            return data
        }
    })
}
```

estou testando com um console.log(), e retorna promisse{pending}

esta aqui é a versao com o then, nao sei se esta certo

```
async function emailExi(email){ 
    const teste = await $.ajax({
        url: "../banco/emailexi.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {email: email},
    }).then(function(data){
        return data
    })
}

var tr = emailExi("aa")

console.log(tr)
```

Entao eu tenho 2 funções:

```
function valiEmail(email){
let erro = false

if (emailExi(inputEmail)){
erro = "email já existe. Por favor coloque outro email"
}

return erro
}
```

```
async function emailExi(email){ 
    const teste = await $.ajax({
        url: "../banco/emailexi.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {email: email},
    })
    return teste
}
```

eu quero retornar se é true ou false lá pra função valiEmail, como faço isso?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o `then` para capturar as informações?

Comment: tentei, mas nao sei se fiz certo

Answer (score 2):

Se for utilizar o `await`, não precisa do `success` ou `then` dentro da função. Precisará do `then` apenas quando não estiver já num escopo assíncrono.

```js
async function get_title(id) {
  const data = await $.ajax(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`);
  
  return data.title;
}

// Pode obter o resultado utilizando o then
get_title(1).then(title => console.log(title));

// Ou usando o await dentro de uma função async
(async () => {
  const title = await get_title(1);
  console.log(title);
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: eu coloquei o then fora da função, mas como faço pra retornar o valor? eu preciso retornar o valor da consulta

Comment: Está na resposta, a função `get_title` retorna o valor da consulta. A questão é que como é uma função assíncrona, você precisa acessar o retorno usando o `await`, quando dentro de um bloco assíncrono, ou capturar a resolução da promessa via função `then`. A resposta mostra os dois exemplos.

Comment: de fato retorna, mas eu quero saber como retornar esse valor pra 1 funçao que eu chamei

Comment: eu tenho uma funçao que chama essa função ajax, preciso retonar o valor pra essa 1 funcao, nao pra uma 3 função

Comment: De novo, existem dois exemplos que fazem isso na resposta. O que não entendeu?

Comment: entao, a resposta chega nessas funções de exemplo, so que eu queria colocar esse valor em uma variavel e retonar la pra função mae, onde tudo isso começou. vou editar a pergunta pra vc entender melhor

Comment: @alguemAi `const existe = await emailExi(inputEmail)`, basta fazer isso antes do seu `if` e fazer `if (existe)`

Comment: dessa vez teve outro problema, dava erro pq so da pra usar o await em funçoes assincronas, ai transformei a função em assincrona, mas na hr de retornar o valor dessa função, retorna uma promessa. E eu ate tentei separar em outra função, mas ai o codigo nao espera essa outra função terminar

Comment: Claramente você ainda não domina bem os conceitos de funções assíncronas, então sugiro que revise os seus estudos antes de continuar. Uma documentação que geralmente me ajuda a entender alguns conceitos é a MDN, veja a página sobre funções assíncronas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Realmente nao entendo, eu sei o que é assincrono e sincrono, mas na pratica nao consigo usar, ja estou faz tempo tentando usar, e ate agr nada, o pior é que nao entendo nada dessas docs. vlw pela ajuda